# Arithmetics, calculate the number of books in the library

Tags: sequences-and-series

A library currently has 120000 books. In the coming years, the library plans to purchase 4000 books per year. At the same time, the books wear out, so it is estimated that 2.5% of the books must be discarded. After how many years does it happen that as many books as are bought are discarded? How many books does the library have then?

I am supposed to solve this using arithmetics, but I have no idea how. However, I do notice that there are two questions:

1. After how many years does it happen that as many books as are bought are discarded?
2. How many books does the library have then?

Maybe we are supposed to use our notion of arithmetic sequences? Or geometric sequences?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many books get discarded the 1st year? the 2nd year? the 3rd? See a pattern?

Comment: In the first year, zero books are discarded. What happens next?

Comment: If you are familiar with algebra, I can give you the advice to solve it first by algebra first ($0.025(120000+x4000)=4000$), then construct an arithmetical reasoning out of it.

Comment: so the solution to that equation is $x=10$

Comment: but i dont know what it means or how to construct an arithemtical reasoning out of it

Comment: In terms of sequences, it's a combination of arithmetic and geometric: $a_{n+1} = (1-0.025)a_{n} + 4000$. Though I doubt you're supposed to analyze it like that.

Comment: If you've learnt compound interest, then this is like a problem with negative interest rate ($-2.5\%$) and recurring deposit (4000). Though I think it's algebraic at this point.

Comment: you are on the right track... ive looked at some forums with similiar questions and they also come up with the idea of a combination of arithmetic and geometric sequences

Comment: I have also seen an approach where they use differential equations to solve it, but that doesnt belong to arithmetic

Comment: My interpretation is that in the 1st year $2.5\%$ of the $120,000$ books are discarded.

Answer (score 2):

When is there a balance between the "in" and the "out" ?

First convert 2.5% into the fraction $1/40$ ;

When do a 40th part of the content of the library balances $4000$ ?

Evidently when the library has  $40 \times 4000 = 160000$ books ;

How long has it taken to pass from the present stat $120000$ to the future state $160000$, i.e., how long has it taken to have $40000$ new books at the rythm of $4000$ per year ? Evidently  when $10$ years have elapsed.

Comment: Now, I have doubt : shouldn't the 2.5% discarded books be subtracted from the incoming $4000$ ? In this case, it's too difficult to be solved by pure arithmetical reasoning...

Comment: I agree. Either one must manually calculate each year, or use algebra.

Comment: The incoming 4000 books are new. They haven't worn out yet and thus should not be discarded. It is only the remaining books from the year prior that should have 2.5% of its books discarded.

Comment: I haven't been clear in this "caveat" : I meant that one could consider that for example, at the end of the first year, there are only 97.5 % of the $120000$, i.e., $117000$ books that are "promoted" to the next year... and the following year $97.5%$ of $117000$ (or $117000+4000$), etc. which is a completely different problem, assimilable to compound interests calculation, well beyond "ordinary arithmetic".

Answer (score 1):

Here's my interpretation. However many books there are at the start of the year, at the end there are that many, times $0.975$, plus $4000$. The "times $0.975$" comes from discarding $2.5\%$ of the books, so $97.5\%$ remain.

So, after one year, $(120000)(.975)+4000$.

After two years, $((120000)(.975)+4000)(.975)+4000=(120000)(.975)^2+(4000)(1+.975)$.

After three years, $((120000)(.975)^2+(4000)(1+.975))(.975)+4000$ which simplifies to $(120000)(.975)^3+(4000)(1+.975+.975^2)$.

A pattern emerges: after $n$ years, $(120000)(.975)^n+(4000)(1+.975+\cdots+.975^{n-1})$.

That last bit is a geometric series with $n$ terms, first term $1$, common ratio $.975$, so it adds up to $(1-.975^n)/.025$.

Now that you know how many books are there, you can multiply by $.025$ to get the number discarded, then set that equal to $4000$ and solve for $n$.

Comment: This is also, as I commented, a very logical answer...